# firewall windows server 2012 r2 with DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2

under windows server environment 2012 I have a DHCP server and I have a firewall under my machine, the firewall blocks all already. the problem that the DHCP server does not give an address to the client, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, welcome. I would like to help you. I am not knowledgeable about windows server but I am familiar with windows 10 firewall as I have struggled many times with it. Can you tell us what you have tried already so we can better help you?

Comment: I adminstrate a secure network infrastructure by windows server i work with two network cards one for WAN@192.168.1.0/24 and one for LAN@192.168.2.0/24 and i do the routing between them I need to secure the traffic between the two cards and block all incoming and outgoing traffic and allow only the internet connection on the server. but it blocks it is implemented only on the server machine against it must implementer also on the client for example the rules of sharing or network discovery are blocked by default but the client of ip address192.168.2.3 sees the other device the WAN

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. the solution is the addition of an outgoing rule for DHCP that is on the UDP protocol that allows the local port 67 and for the destination one is allowed the port 68